# Weblogic capacity sizing

Tags: oracle, weblogic11g

Please can anyone suggest.We are trying to estimate how manay managed server instances are required in a weblogic domain and how many servers would we need as well.
Our estimate is that on  there will be 10,000 concurrent users(doesn't include logged in users) for the application
and about 400 transactions per second and each http session will carry around 40kB data..

1. How many managed servers would we
   ideally need ?
2. How many windows vm's & cpu's would we need ideally.Each windows vm has memory of 4gb
3. We are planning to allocate atleast 1 Gb memory to each managed server.
   the weblogic environment will be on virtualisation farm with each vm having around 5GB memory..

Many thanks

Comment: 10,000 *concurrent* users? Really? That's quite a lot. Anyway, there is no single answer to this question.

Comment: 10'000 concurrent users with 400 transactions per second means that each request takes 25 seconds (on average). This sounds like too much. Or are there a lot of requests that don't cause a transaction? Don't you count read-only requests as transactions?

Comment: For a serious estimate, you'll need to determine how much CPU time a request use, how much memory it temporarily requires, how big your session data is, how long each requests takes, what the typical distribution  between short and long requests is, how many database queries you submit etc. Or just test how many users you can server with just a single server.

Comment: 10000 users might not be entirely accurate but 400 transactions per second is.Within these transactions some of them might just be reading some data and not all of them are updates or writes.I need to understand that on basis of say 3-5 second per transaction and assuming each of it might take say around 5 secs cpu time.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is impossible to size an architecture armed with just numbers like this. I realize that's all you got right now, but I would recommend you set up one of your servers, place a servlet there that simulates your transaction time and use a tool like JMeter to hit it to see where it breaks.

BTW, there can be many other bottlenecks - is your database up to handling 400 transactions/sec?